# Where can I find NBA stats for shots made or missed after a foul?

Tags: statistics, nba

I am looking for the names of websites that show NBA team season percentages of 2 point and 3 point shots that were made and missed after a foul.

Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A shot that is missed, after a foul, doesn't count as a field goal attempt, so I don't think it's really possible or useful to keep track of it

Comment: How many times a team went to the line for 1 or 2 shots after a foul and for 1 or 3 shots after a foul?